# publishing problems with shiny io using the sf library and leaflet

Tags: r

I have a basic code using leaflet in which I use a shapefile that works perfectly using it locally, but when I publish it it creates the link with an error message.
I checked to see if the problem was in the leaflet library but when I placed a custom polygon the publication ran successfully.
I appreciate your help in solving the problem... :)

This is the code that works locally but I couldn't publish i

````
---
title: "Dashboard Interactivo"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
```
```{r}
UCPN = read_sf("DATA/11_UCPNs_Fin.shp")
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Mapa Interactivo


```{r}
leafletOutput("map", height = 600)
UCPN_transformado = st_transform(UCPN, crs = 4326)
```

```{r}
 # Cargar el shapefile

# Creación del output del mapa
# Renderizado del mapa
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() %>%  # Añadir los tiles base del mapa
    addPolygons(data = UCPN_transformado)  # Añadir el polígono del shapefile
})

```
````

Comment: What is the error??

Comment: @r2evans is right. We need more information. But as a first guess, `read_sf("DATA/11_UCPNs_Fin.shp")` is attempting to read a local file on your own machine, and that file cannot be accessed in that way from the remote server.

Comment: Checkout section [2.1.3.2 System Packages](https://docs.posit.co/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html) and its link to https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies

Comment: It is practically a shapefile inside the local directory. I have no problems running it locally, but when I go to publish it I get the message (Error: "An error has occurred. Please check your logs or contact the application author for clarification.") I leave the link:      https://harpia.shinyapps.io/visualizador/

Comment: Still, there's nothing we can do about "an error has occurred" without seeing what the error is. Your app on shinyapps.io should provide some logs, those logs (stdout and stderr, perhaps) should provide more clarity on the error.  My guess: either (a) your `.shp` file was not among the file manifest, so it is not found; or (b) the `sf` library needs some OS packages as well, though from 2.1.3.2 (prev comment) they suggest that `sf` is known and its supporting libraries should be available. Most likely my "a", `file not found`.

Comment: @mauricioillescas, only you can access app logs, once logged in to admin dashboard
 ( https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/dashboard ), select your app and check the Logs tab.